# ALB ingress work on http but fail on https

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

Hi I am deploying an react application on AWS EKS. After I applied my ingress, I can visit the webpage using http://, but got a dns error on https. Does anyone have an idea where might be wrong?

```
service:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 8080
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: my-alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS

  hosts:
    - host: ui.XXXX.com
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            serviceName: my-ui
            servicePort: 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

For port 443 to work you need to have a TLS certificate.

Please create a TLS certificate which includes your hostname ui.XXXX.com using  AWS Certificate Manager.

Then add the certificate ARN to your ingress with the annotation

alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: your certificate arn